# How can I increment in JSP in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, jsp, increment

I have a problem with incrementing a variable in JSP inside a javascript loop.

My code is something like this:

```
"<%int index = 0%>;"; <- this without quotion marks

for(var j = 0; j < <%= 3 %>; j++)
{

    <%varname++;%>;

    alert("<% out.print(varname); %>");
}
```

And the result is: 1, then 1, then 1, instead of 1, then 2, then 3.

Comment: JSP and JavaScript don't work like that. JSP runs on the server to generate what is essentially a plain-text stream that is then sent to the client and then the JavaScript runs there. The two do not run simultaneously.

Comment: My problem is I have a java class, it have a String[] field, and I want to iterate through this array in my jsp and generate element src by it.